# Hide the html5 video play button in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I searched the web but couldn't find the selector for hiding the play button in firefox.

Here's an example video
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: Wondering if you ever found a solution for this. I tried several, but the issue persists for Firefox.